# how to make a color spinner and when i choose one color from that spinner that time change layout color

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, spinner

`spinner = green yellow black red blue`

`when i choose blue`

1. i need whole layout color should be " BLUE "
2. please help me to build this with xml file and java code

xml file =

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/sp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:entries="@array/color_ar" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="ok"
    android:text="set background" />
```

java code =

public class BackgroundSpinner extends AppCompatActivity {

```
RelativeLayout layout;
Spinner sp;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test);

    sp = findViewById(R.id.sp);
    layout = findViewById(R.id.layout);

    layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
}

public void ok(View view) {

    String a = sp.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

i need green, yellow, black, red, blue these colors in spinner and when i
choose blue i need whole layout color should be blue

Comment: Hi Jemish please show what code you have written so that a contributor can proceed form there on wards.